# what is the maximum allowed field length for the fulfillment tracking number

Tags: api, shopify, fulfillment

What is the maximum allowed field length for the fulfillment tracking number if edited through the Shopify API? I have instances where more than one tracking number may be required for a line item (if, for instance, the customer orders enough quantity that multiple boxes must be shipped and not all go in the same shipment). Can I insert a comma-delimited string of tracking numbers, and if so, what's the maximum allowed length of the string?

Answer (score 1):

255 chars: Shopify represents it internally as a string type with ActiveRecord.

Edward Ocampo-Gooding, Shopify Developer Advocate

Comment: Thanks, Edward. Now if only Shopify could take the comma-delimited tracking numbers and create separate links for each in the customer notification email... ;-)